# Properly set "cancel button" in a MessageBox with ID_OKCANCEL; dialog within a dialog

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, messagebox, cancel-button

I hope my description will make everything clearer.

The idea is I have to create a sort of phonebook, that uses a List Control (as report), has a menu and can be saved (to an external file), loaded (from one) and you can add new contacts, edit and delete existing contacts. 
I have to use new dialogs when adding and editing contacts. Like, I have a menu button named "add contact" that opens a new dialog with edit boxes (in which you type the first name, last name, phonenumber etc.). 
The phonebook works, there are no errors, but I want to make it a bit better, functional:

Let's say I already have a contact named John Doe. If I try to add a contact named exactly John Doe, when I click the "add" button, I set the program to ask me:
"Contact name already exists; other details will be changed accordingly" with the OK and CANCEL options.
If I click OK, everything works, of course. The phone,email, adress and group (that's the rest of info) are changed. If I click Cancel the dialog for the "add" just disappears and it goes back to my main dialog which shows the list. That's also the code's thing, but I want it to ... do nothing. If I click that CANCEL, I want it to get back to my "add contact dialog window", but by keeping the edit boxes already completed like before I pressed "add" button. Because I can just call the function again if I click cancel, but that way I just get a new "add dialog" with empty edit boxes and that's not really what I want.
The same thing I want to happen when I insert a new contact (first and last name), but the phone number and/or the email I set in the edit boxes already exist(s). Like, it will say in a message: "Phone number already exists"; and if I click "OK" it should just return to the main dialog (the list, report), but if I click "CANCEL" I want it to return to the "add dialog" with unchanged edit boxes (the before-typed first name, last name, phone, adress, email, group) unchanged, so I can just edit the phone/email that already existed.

I hope you guys understand the idea. I know it's a lot of text. By the way, the group is chosen with radio buttons, if it matters.

The code for the Insert Function is below; I tried to translate the variables in English for now, so it's an easier read (I'm not native English speaker, sorry for possible mistakes);

```
void Phonebook::OnContactAdd() // keep in mind this is everything in the programs Dlg.cpp (PhonebookDlg.cpp)
{
    Add newcontact; //the Add type, the class created for the add dialog, has some TCHAR* values FirstName, LastName etc. When I click "add button" in the add dialog, the text from the edit boxes goes accordingly to the TCHARs
    if (newcontact.DoModal()==IDOK)
    {
        TCHAR getFirstName[20],getLastName[20],getPhoneNo[20],getAdr[100],getEmail[30]; //after the classes "newcontact" TCHARs are set, these strings from here get the values already in the list and it compares them
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<list.GetItemCount();i++) // it compares the values in the edit boxes typed in the "add dialog" with the ones in each line already in the list
        {
            list.GetItemText(i,0,getFirstName,20); //gets the first name from line i
            list.GetItemText(i,1,getLastName,20);// gets last name from line i
            if (strcmp(getFirstName,newcontact.FirstName)==0 && strcmp(getLastName,newcontact.LastName)==0) //compares the firstname and lastname introduced with those from the line i and if they're equal...
                if (MessageBox("Contact name already exists; other details will be changed accordingly","Warning!",MB_ICONQUESTION | MB_OKCANCEL | MB_TOPMOST )==IDOK)
                {
                    list.SetItemText(i,2,newcontact.PhoneNo);
                    prefix(i,newcontact.PhoneNo);//function that determines the operator, not relevant to the problem
                    list.SetItemText(i,4,newcontact.Adr);
                    list.SetItemText(i,5,newcontact.Email);
                    setgrup(i,newcontact.grup); // again, this is a function that sets the group in the list according to the radio button checked; ignore it, not relevant to the problem
                    return; // it found something, it changed, it exists
                }
                //else IDCANCEL; // this is the problem! else what? if I put "else return", it exists to the list, of course; if i set "else OnCancel()" it closes the whole program
                list.GetItemText(i,2,getPhoneNo,20); // if the names are not equal, we go and check if the phone number already exists
                if (strcmp(getPhoneNo,newcontact.PhoneNo)==0)
                {
                    AfxMessageBox("Phone number already exists");
                    OnContactAdd(); //it exists and now the function is called again; that's what I was saying, but it's not what I want, I want to "cancel" and go back to editing the text boxes
                    return;
                }

                list.GetItemText(i,5,getEmail,30);//same thing for the mail, as for the phone number
                if (strcmp(getEmail,newcontact.Email)==0)
                {
                    AfxMessageBox("Email already exists");
                    OnContactAdd();
                    return;
                }
        }
        // if the names, phone number or email weren't already in the list, there is no special case, so we just add the input data to the top of the list
        list.InsertItem(0,newcontact.FirstName);
        list.SetItemText(0,1,newcontact.LastName);
        list.SetItemText(0,2,newcontact.PhoneNo);
        list.SetItemText(0,4,newcontact.Adr);
        list.SetItemText(0,5,newcontact.Email);
        prefix(0,newcontact.PhoneNo);
        setgrup(0,newcontact.grup);
    }
}
```

//
Now one more question (secondary), maybe someone knows about it and randomly enters here:

I have to make a "search as you type option". I did that. But it should also colour the found text. Assuming I'm searching for "Jo" and there's a "John" and a "Joanne", only those lines (all the columns, the info, proper to the found names) should appear. No problem, I did that. But is there a way to colour/bold/highlight only the Jo from John and Joanne? Like get the Jo-es red and the rest ('hn' and 'anne' to stay black). Or at least to get the whole text colored, but the other column text to stay black, default.
For searching I use an event handler from an edit box, compare the text from the box to every column in the list, line by line. If there is a match, the line is added to a new list control that is hidden by default, and it comes in front now. Hope you understand this. Probably I'll make another topic for this also.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your Add class here? I think you should handle saving the contact inside the "Add" CDialog class.

Pressing the "OK" button and calling OnOk() (IDOK) function starts closing the dialog window.
You're calling EndDialog() function by pressing it and you are not handling any events inside of it (you are doing it outside of the dialog - after closing it) so the dialog starts closing. Check this nice example, it really shows the point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wddd3ztw(v=vs.80).aspx.

By the time you call OnCancel() when displaying this message box ""Contact name already exists; other details will be changed accordingly" the main dialog's OnCancel() will be called as you'd already left the Add dialog scope. Once again, I would advise you to handle saving the contact inside the "Add" class. Try making a function handling a "Save" button that will check all the conditions and perform the appropriate action. You can also try overriding the OnOk() function but I'd go for the function. Put the function inside the "Add" dialog box so it can perform all the necessary checks inside this instance of the "Add" class.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that's the problem. I solved it with a workaround (created an "exception" function that receives the text from the edit boxes as parameters; it's basically another call to the "AddContact" function, but with parameteres that will be set from the start in the edit boxes;Right after calling the "Exception()" I have a return, so the ADD function will just end (in cascade). I know it's not pretty,but trying to do the whole thing in the ADD dialog.cpp would mean to rewrite a good part of my code. I tried that first,but I couldn't because the contacts are stored in a list control.